# Crop or Clip image to Circle using JointJS

Tags: javascript, jointjs

I'm very new to both JointJS and SVG, so I am having a hard time interpreting some of the documentation for JointJS. I am trying to get randomly searched images to display in a circle for this project, in a graph that uses JointJS to display and link the images with arrows. I am convinced this shouldn't be as hard as I am making it, but I have spent hours going through the documentation, so I need help. From what I can tell, joint.shapes.standard.Circle elements cannot take an image as a background or fill. I would be really happy to use the .BorderedImage elements, but when I change the radius to make them a circle, the border changes without cropping the image. I also tried to use the .Image element and change the radius, and again the image didn't change. I am under the impression that I could add a clipPath definition to an .Image or .BorderedImage to force a circle, but I am not familiar enough with the syntax to be clear on where to do that, and none of the examples I have found on stackoverflow have given me enough information to do that. I tried using the .define method, and kept getting "cannot read property define of undefined" errors, so I know I wasn't using that right. 
Here's what I have in the way of error-free code (rounded border that doesn't crop):

```
var graph = new joint.dia.Graph;

    var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
        el: document.getElementById('myholder'),
        model: graph,
        width: 600,
        height: 600,
        gridSize: 1,
        // makes code not draggable
        interactive: { elementMove: false, arrowheadMove: false }
    });
var borderedImage = new joint.shapes.standard.BorderedImage();
    borderedImage.resize(100, 100);
    borderedImage.position(100, 100);
    borderedImage.attr('root/title', 'joint.shapes.standard.BoarderedImage');
    borderedImage.attr('label/text', 'Monster\nImage');
    borderedImage.attr('border/rx', "50%");
    borderedImage.attr('image/xlinkHref', './assets/images/monster.svg');
    borderedImage.addTo(graph);
```

The code I tried for .define looked like:

```
joint.shapes.Element.define('standard.BorderedImage', {
        attrs: {
            body: {
                rx: "50%"
            }
        }
    })
```

Some of the resources I have looked at and couldn't figure out how to use correctly are: 
[Putting multiple films in a circle in Raphael/Joint.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363951/putting-multiple-films-in-a-circle-in-raphael-joint-js) 
[How to set background image for a rectangle in JointJs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41851548/how-to-set-background-image-for-a-rectangle-in-jointjs) 
[Using predefined SVG file for creating a custom JointJS shape with ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37152510/using-predefined-svg-file-for-creating-a-custom-jointjs-shape-with-ports) 
https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v2.1/joint.html#dia.Paper.prototype.properties